# Ensure yum install fails if post install script fails

Tags: linux, centos, yum, rhel

When trying to install a yum package, I'm getting:

```
Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure in rpm package
```

But the yum install is completing successfully, so it's tough to know when it failed or not.

Anyway to fail when yum encounters this?

Comment: Have you checked the Postinstall script? You can get rpm scripts using `rpm -q --scripts packageName`

Comment: @dlmeetei yep, I wrote the postinstall script. I'm intentionally triggering an exit 1, which I'd like to cause yum to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You must update your `selinux-policy` package. Check [RPM scriptlets
  fail during updates](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F20_bugs#RPM_scriptlets_fail_during_updates)
- Just ensure you have the right kernel-headers installed for your running kernel and you should be fine. According to [trouble installing on Fedora and CentOS](https://lists.zx2c4.com/pipermail/wireguard/2017-August/001656.html)
- And finally, check this bug: [Fedora 25 Install from DVD ISO Fails DNF error: Non-fatal POSTIN scriptlet failure](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1398847)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the forest through the trees but I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: @jojoob step by step :)